# Android Desktop Pictures gradually become vague

Tags: android, desktop

I make a desktop and obtain the app icon. But it become vague than the original desktop. I don’t know why. The icon’s size is the same.
The layout:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:paddingTop="15dip">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/appIcon"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="40dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/appName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="#FFFF"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Get app code:

```
final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        //get all apps
        final List<ResolveInfo> apps = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

        GridView appPage = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.all_app_grid);
        appPage.setAdapter(new AppAdapter(this, apps));
```

And I get the app icon code from monitor:

```
Bitmap bmp = Utilities.createIconBitmap(appInfo.loadIcon(pm), mContext);        
appItem.mAppIcon.setImageDrawable(appInfo.loadIcon(pm));
static Bitmap createIconBitmap(Drawable icon, Context context) {
synchronized (sCanvas) { // we share the statics :-(
if (sIconWidth == -1) {
initStatics(context);
}

        int width = sIconWidth;
        int height = sIconHeight;

        if (icon instanceof PaintDrawable) {
            PaintDrawable painter = (PaintDrawable) icon;
            painter.setIntrinsicWidth(width);
            painter.setIntrinsicHeight(height);
        } else if (icon instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            // Ensure the bitmap has a density.
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) icon;
            Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            if (bitmap.getDensity() == Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE) {
                bitmapDrawable.setTargetDensity(context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            }
        }
        int sourceWidth = icon.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int sourceHeight = icon.getIntrinsicHeight();

        if (sourceWidth > 0 && sourceHeight > 0) {
            // There are intrinsic sizes.
            if (width < sourceWidth || height < sourceHeight) {
                // It's too big, scale it down.
                final float ratio = (float) sourceWidth / sourceHeight;
                if (sourceWidth > sourceHeight) {
                    height = (int) (width / ratio);
                } else if (sourceHeight > sourceWidth) {
                    width = (int) (height * ratio);
                }
            } else if (sourceWidth < width && sourceHeight < height) {
                // Don't scale up the icon
                width = sourceWidth;
                height = sourceHeight;
            }
        }

        // no intrinsic size --> use default size
        int textureWidth = sIconTextureWidth;
        int textureHeight = sIconTextureHeight;

        final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(textureWidth, textureHeight,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        final Canvas canvas = sCanvas;
        canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);

        final int left = (textureWidth-width) / 2;
        final int top = (textureHeight-height) / 2;

        if (false) {
            // draw a big box for the icon for debugging
            canvas.drawColor(sColors[sColorIndex]);
            if (++sColorIndex >= sColors.length) sColorIndex = 0;
            Paint debugPaint = new Paint();
            debugPaint.setColor(0xffcccc00);
            canvas.drawRect(left, top, left+width, top+height, debugPaint);
        }

        sOldBounds.set(icon.getBounds());
        icon.setBounds(left, top, left+width, top+height);
        icon.draw(canvas);
        icon.setBounds(sOldBounds);
        canvas.setBitmap(null);

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this to check if the screen density is right:
context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

if not, set your desktop app's manifest, make your android:targetSdkVersion larger then 4. then the screen density will be right.